# Array of pointers holds the same value for all elements

Tags: c++, pointers, custom-object

I'm currently deep-diving into the way pointers work.

Something for me unexplainable happened when executing the following lines of code:

```
        std::vector<OptimizerPlanOperatorPtr> sources;
        for (const auto &source : sourceOperators){
            OptimizerPlanOperator planOperator = OptimizerPlanOperator(source);
            sources.push_back(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<OptimizerPlanOperator>(&planOperator));
        }
```

all `sourceOperators` differ, however when checking the elements of `sources`, they all point to the same `OptimizerPlanOperator`.

When I ran the debugger, I realized that in every loop step, all values of `sources`
change to the recent value.

My assumption is, that I poorly initialized the pointer here which somehow results in the value the pointer refers to being overridden.

Can somebody show a solution or explain, what I did wrong here?

Comment: What is `OptimizerPlanOperatorPtr`? What are you trying to do with that `static_cast` over there?

Comment: Side note: "overridden" != "overwritten", even though they sound alike in American.

Comment: `OptimizerPlanOperator(source)` probably should return a `std::shared_ptr<OptimizerPlanOperator>` so then you would have `auto planOperator = OptimizerPlanOperator(source);` and `sources.push_back(planOperator);` and no dangling pointer or trying to free a stack variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing the location of an object whose lifetime ends with the current iteration *and* handing ownership of it to a `shared_ptr`.  Both are problems that lead to undefined behaviour.

Casting a pointer to `std::shared_ptr` does not automagically make the pointed-to object into a shared object and extend its lifetime, and it is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<OptimizerPlanOperator>(&planOperator)`.

The simplest solution is to not do this stepwise but all at once:

```
for (const auto &source : sourceOperators){
    sources.push_back(std::make_shared<OptimizerPlanOperator>(source));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `planOperator` is a local variable on the stack, and when you are passing it to the cast `static_cast<std::shared_ptr<OptimizerPlanOperator>(&planOperator)`, you are passing in the address of a local variable, so as soon as the iteration is over, that pointer `&planOperator` becomes garbage.